# Elasticsearch snapshot to Azure blob storage - Can not find an azure client for account

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-blob-storage, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to update the Azure storage account that we upload snapshots to but I get the below error:
"Can not find an azure client for account [null]]" this is only happening when I change the storage account. This new storage account is in a different region and subscription. Please let me know if there's any other details that may be helpful.

NOTE: Same error as [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-while-creating-elasticsearch-azure-repository-for-snapshot-and-restore/61248) topic but I saw that it was closed. I have double checked my credentials and storage account name and I believe them to be correct.

**Environment**
OS: Centos7
Elasticsearch Version: 2.4.6
Plugin: cloud-azure-2.4.6.zip
(https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/cloud-azure/2.4.6/cloud-azure-2.4.6.zip)

**/etc/Elasticsearch/Elasticsearch.yml**

```
...
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ['<IP1>', '<IP2>', '<IP3>', '<IP4>', '<IP5>']
cloud.azure.storage.opening.account: "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME"
cloud.azure.storage.opening.key: "SECRET_KEY"
...
```

**create_snapshot.sh**

```
$ curl -X PUT "<IP>:9200/_snapshot/${repo}/${backup}?wait_for_completion=true&pretty"
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "repository_exception",
      "reason" : "[elasticsearch-snapshots] Can not find an azure client for account [null]"
    } ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[elasticsearch-snapshots] Can not find an azure client for account [null]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Can not find an azure client for account [null]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

**Full Log**

```
[2021-11-09 11:18:40,215][WARN ][rest.suppressed          ] path: /_snapshot/jibeio/production_2021-11-09-11-17, params: {pretty=, repository=jibeio, wait_for_completion=true, snapshot=productio
n_2021-11-09-11-17}
RemoteTransportException[[Bentley Wittman][<ip>:9300][cluster:admin/snapshot/create]]; nested: RepositoryException[[elasticsearch-snapshots] Can not find an azure client for account [nul
l]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Can not find an azure client for account [null]];
Caused by: RepositoryException[[elasticsearch-snapshots] Can not find an azure client for account [null]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Can not find an azure client for account [null]];
        at org.elasticsearch.cloud.azure.storage.AzureStorageServiceImpl.createContainer(AzureStorageServiceImpl.java:168)
        at org.elasticsearch.cloud.azure.blobstore.AzureBlobStore.createContainer(AzureBlobStore.java:117)
        at org.elasticsearch.repositories.azure.AzureRepository.initializeSnapshot(AzureRepository.java:164)
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.beginSnapshot(SnapshotsService.java:305)
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService.access$600(SnapshotsService.java:91)
        at org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotsService$1$1.run(SnapshotsService.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find an azure client for account [null]
        at org.elasticsearch.cloud.azure.storage.AzureStorageServiceImpl.getSelectedClient(AzureStorageServiceImpl.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.cloud.azure.storage.AzureStorageServiceImpl.createContainer(AzureStorageServiceImpl.java:162)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check if reference can narrow down the issue.

- According to the traced error, it seems like missing a container to store snapshot or client account name (ignore as you have already confiremed to be right) must be possible causes.
- elasticsearch-snapshots is configurable by adding the`cloud.azure.storage.default.container` parameter to your   `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file with the name of the    container that you would like to store the snapshots in, or by passing
  the container option on the HTTP request.
- Or if that’s not the case , check if you have given properly configured account name > ("{{storage-account-name}}.blob.core.windows.net")  and key to all nodes that has account name in the cluster.
- Try using different key from key1 or key2
- Also check [[this repository-azure-usage]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-azure-usage.html)
- If everything was configured correctly ,Please check if there is firewall or a proxy that is blocking the access.

> To properly trace the exception.Send below request in logging.yml file
>
> ```
> PUT /_cluster/settings
> {
>     "transient" : {
>         "logger.cloud.azure.storage" : "TRACE"
>     }
> }
> ```

If issue remains you may raise a support request by going to overview page > support+troubleshooting> new support request.

**References:**
[archive-elasticsearch-indices-to-azure-blob-storage-using-the-azure-cloud-plugin](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/archive-elasticsearch-indices-to-azure-blob-storage-using-the-azure-cloud-plugin/#:%7E:text=The%20Azure%20Cloud%20plugin%20for%20Elasticsearch%20adds%20some,highly%20available%20option%20for%20recovery%20of%20your%20indices.)

Comment: Thanks kavyasaraboju-MT for the options! 
1. I have confirmed the account name and container are correct 
2. "{{storage-account-name}}.blob.core.windows.net" is set correctly on all nodes. I can supply example code to the main comment if that would make it any clearer?
3. I have tried both keys but no luck
4. Is there somewhere in particular I need to check for firewall/proxy access to the storage account? 
5. I sent that request but maybe I have misunderstood something because I seem to just get the same error as before.

Let me know if there's any other information I can give!